# Images floating off footer

Tags: css, footer, fixed

I have a `position:fixed` footer on my page so that it scrolls with the page. Inside that footer I have a set of five images. The problem is that the images all hang off the bottom of the footer so the bottoms are not visible. No margin or padding values have moved them to the appropriate place on screen. Is there a css command I am missing or is their something weird with the footer?

This is the css for the footer and images within it. Thanks for any help.

```
.footer { 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    height: 100px; 
    font-size:20px; 
    color:black; 
    font-family:Verdana;
    padding-left: 8px;  
    width: 100%; 
    position:fixed; left:0px; bottom:100px; 
}

.footer img{
    width: 59px;
    height: 90px;
    float: right;
    display:inline;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="header"></div>

<div class="content">

  <div class="leftSidebar">
    <div align="center"> 
      <h3>Quick Stats</h3>
    </div>
    <p>Title: Exposure</p>
    <p>Author: Kathy/Brendan Reichs</p>
    <p>Series: Virals</p>
    <p>Length: 436 pages</p>
    <p>Publication Date: March 6, 2014    </p>
    <p align="center"><a href="../Images/Barnes-and-Noble.png"><img src="../Images/Barnes-and-Noble.png" width="180" height="120" /></a><img src="../Images/amazon.png" width="180" height="98.18" style="z-index: -1;" /></p>
  </div>

<div class="rightSidebar">
    <div align="center"> 
      <h3>Kathy Reichs</h3>
    </div>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br><br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br></p>
</div>

<div class="middleBar">
  <div class="bookTitle" align="center">
    <h1>Virals: Exposure</h1>
    <h2 style="font-size:24px;">Kathy and Brendan Reichs</h2> 
  </div>
  <div align="center"><img name="" src="../Exposure.jpg" width="315" height="456" alt="" /></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <div class="relatedBooks">
    <p>Related Books: ssssss </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footerImages">
    <img src="../Images/Swipe.jpg" width="1000" height="1500" />
    <img src="../Images/Code.jpg" width="59" height="90"  />
    <img src="../Images/Shift.jpg" width="1000" height="1500" />
    <img src="../Images/Seizure.jpg" width="327" height="500" />
    <img src="../Images/Virals.jpg" width="327" height="500"  />
    </div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. What is wrong with it here? http://jsbin.com/zajuhidi/2/edit

Comment: Indeed @TimHayes, your [code appears to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/wdYLU/1/). Are you talking about when the screen width gets too narrow and the images float below one another?

Comment: no the images that are flowed into the .footer appear slightly below the bottom of the footer. I need them shifted up to be in the middle of the footer.

Comment: Where is your HTML markup?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the "height: 100px;". It will be set to auto then, and if you want some more space around the images then use something like "padding: 24px 0;" to space it out a bit. There's no reason to declare the height of the footer. It will auto-grow to the size of your images. I imagine that's why they're floating off.